# WPF XAML Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Hello
I have a problem with a binding that I want to do and can't find any information on how to do it.
Basically I want to bind an object to a property of another object.
For example

```
<TextBox Text="test" Tag="{Binding ElementName=TxtBx2}" x:Name="TxtBx1"/>
<TextBox Text="test" x:Name="TxtBx2"/>
```

This is kind of weird but it would help on the code that i'm implementing, so on a property of one object I want to have another object bind in xaml.

I don't know if this is possible, any pointers would be helpful
Thanks, Ruben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how you do it; you just need to specify the `Path`.

```
<TextBox Text="test" Tag="{Binding ElementName=TxtBx2, Path=Text}" x:Name="TxtBx1"/>
<TextBox Text="test" x:Name="TxtBx2"/>
```

If you are wanting the `DataContext` of the `TextBox`; then your Path would change accordingly.

```
<TextBox Text="test" Tag="{Binding ElementName=TxtBx2, Path=DataContext}" x:Name="TxtBx1"/>
<TextBox Text="test" x:Name="TxtBx2"/>
```

If you are needing to use the `Tag` property within a WPF application you might want to re-evaluate your approach as I have yet to use the `Tag` property since moving from WinForms as that need has been replaced by leveraging the data binding functionality within WPF.

**UPDATE:**

If your goal is to bind to a given control versus a property on the control; then don't specify the property name within the `Path`.

Based on your goal; [attached behaviors](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx) would be a better approach and allow you to wrap the functionality within the extended `DataGrid`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I know that I can do that, but I want the object and not just one property.

Comment: I used the Tag property as an example... what i need to do is:I have a Datagrid that I extended from the wpftoolkit datagrid and a user control that is a pager for that Datagrid, so when i move to another page I need to do some processing on the datagrid, so if I could have the pager in the datagrid i could listen to events of that pager, this can sound stupid but is the best idea that I have  for now.... maybe I need to take another aproach.... any ideas are welcome

Comment: @Ruben Updated answer; keep in mind that the data under the control which in this instance is a TextBox should be accessible from outside the control via your ViewModel if you are taking an MVVM approach. Bottom line is that you should NOT need to go to the control to get the data in the majority of scenarios.

Comment: @Ruben Updated answer again; attached behaviors/triggers should suit your needs...

Comment: right know I'm not using mvvm, I just want to use the two controls as one single control, a datagrid with a hability to page if a pager is present in the window and is associated to that datagrid. So when I use it with mvvm I just need to bind the itemsource of the grid to the viewmodel property.... I will have a look at the attached behaviors

Comment: @Ruben The attached behaviors will allow you to provide functionality on the DataGrid; therefore defining the interaction between the DataGrid and the Pager.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBox Text="test" Tag="{Binding ElementName=TxtBx2,Path=Text}" x:Name="TxtBx1"/>
<TextBox Text="test" x:Name="TxtBx2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the value of the Text property of TxtBx1 to be the value of the Text property in TxtBx2, you would use:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtBx1" Text="{Binding ElementName=TxtBx2, Path=Text}" />
<TextBox x:Name="TxtBx2" Text="test" />
```

**Update**

Assuming (possibly incorrectly again!) that you want to bind the TxtBx1 element to the Tag of TxtBx2, you would use:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtBx1" Text="test" />
<TextBox x:Name="TxtBx2" Tag="{Binding ElementName=TxtBx1}" Text="test" />
```

Just out of interest, why do you want to do such a thing?

**Update 2**

Assuming that you have a Datagrid that you've extended from the wpftoolkit datagrid and a user control that is a pager for that Datagrid, and when you move to another page you need to do some processing on the datagrid, then why don't you just either update the datagrid in your page change event (if using code behind), or update the items that the datagrid is bound to in your page change verb on your view model (if using MVVM)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I know that I can do that, but I want the object and not just one property.

Comment: what i need to do is:I have a Datagrid that I extended from the wpftoolkit datagrid and a user control that is a pager for that Datagrid, so when i move to another page I need to do some processing on the datagrid, so if I could have the pager in the datagrid i could listen to events of that pager, this can sound stupid but is the best idea that I have for now.... maybe I need to take another aproach.... any ideas are welcome

Comment: I could do that, but I don't want to have to code on every form or viewmodel that I need paging, I need a way in which i say to the grid this pager is associated to you in the xaml an then the grid is capable of doing what it needs to do is it has a pager associated to it

Answer (score -1):

Well, it does make sense to bind to an entire object(not to any specific property) with items control such as this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="pictureBox" 
ItemsSource=”{Binding Source={StaticResource photos}}" …> 
......
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Could you pelase read his question again? He wrote  "Basically I want to bind an object to a property of another object.". He did not specifically said Control.I gave an example where an entire collection(photos) is bound to a property(ItemsSource) of ListBox.